# How to create a valid selector scss?

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with sass-lint, I don't have any idea how solve this issue.

```
input {
 & + label::after {
   content: none;
 }

 &:checked + label::after {
   content: '';
 }
}
```

Sass-lint message: "Pseudo-element should be nested within its parent Type-selector"

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you try input[type='checkbox'] instead of just input?

Another thing to try is instead of the + to just nest it inside.
so &:checked { label::after { .. } }

Im not that familiar with lint.

Answer (score 0):

try this, its give same result.

```
input {
  + label::after {
   content: none;
  }

 &:checked {
  + label::after {
    content: '';
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
 input {
    & + label {
      &::after {
        content: none;
      }
    }

    &:checked + label {
      &::after {
        content: '';
      }
    }
  }
```